# Vite on Laravel Forge running npm run dev

Tags: laravel, nginx, vite, laravel-forge

We would like to create a dev environment in laravel forge. The site is working correctly, but when we run `npm run dev` it won't load CSS and assets.

How can we configure Nginx on laravel forge and Vite to work with dev environment?

We tried using --host parameter on npm run dev, but still not working.

Comment: The `dev` command is really meant for local development as it provides hot module reload. When you're putting code on a server, just use `build` command and treat it like any other server.

Comment: As Rwd said, you should have a prod build command (namely the default it `npm run prod`) to optimise your bundle sizes, but this isn't likely the issue as both should still generate the working css/js bundles

Comment: Do the bundles get generated as you would expect in your `public` folder after running you're asset-building command?

Comment: If those files do exist can you then make a `get` request to the server to access those bundles? This will at the very least narrow down which part is causing the issue

Comment: I would like to make it to a DEV environment, that's the point. I would like to use it as a local dev environment

Comment: Even if it is a testing environment, you should still use production-optimised assets, the only reason to use `npm run dev` is for convenience on a local machine not having to recompile as often

Comment: either way, your problem is not related to that

Comment: @BenGooding We would like to use it as a dev environment, the programmer will update code with vs code ssh remote plugin, we don't want to create a local dev environment, and this should be a possible solution for our problem. I know what is a production and a test environment, and also know what is a dev environment, so please let me decide what are my needs and why is my problem related to vite...

Comment: i am also using remote server as my development environment and have huge problems with laravel forcing me to create a whole development server instead of just packing the files

Comment: i have found a solution, but it's not very practical. there is no other way though :( https://stackoverflow.com/a/76761568/1916182